# Calculate CloudWatch TimedStorage-ByteHrs costs of log group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

In the Billing section of AWS I can see that CloudWatch generates 3 types of different costs in a full month:

---

- **Amazon CloudWatch** $37.85
  [...]
- **AmazonCloudWatch EUC1-TimedStorage-ByteHrs $89.64**

$0.0324 per GB-mo of log storage - EU (Frankfurt)2,766.686 GB-Mo $89.64

- **AmazonCloudWatch PutLogEvents $93.72** [...]

**Total:** $242.22

---

I am particularly interested in knowing how the `TimedStorage-ByteHrs` is calculated ($89.64). If I have a log group with Stored bytes 12.1 GB, how much is this costing monthly?

PS: In the S3 docs, [I've found a calculation example of TimedStorage-ByteHrs for S3 costs](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#Billing). I tried to apply the same logic (but using the CloudWatch pricing of $0.0324 per GB-mo) to the `AmazonCloudWatch EUC1-TimedStorage-ByteHrs` costs but the result is not correct.